# extract filename and path with slash delimiter from text using grep and lookaround

Tags: regex, grep, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to write a bash script to automate checkin of changed files after comparing a local folder to another remote folder.
To achieve this I am trying to extract the filename with a portion of the path of the remote folder, to be used in the checkin commands. I am seeking assistance on extracting the filename with it's path.

To achieve the comparison I used diff command as follows

```
diff --brief --suppress-common-lines -x '*.class' -ar ~/myprojects/company/apps/product/package/test/ $env_var/java/package/test/
```

The above command prints output in following format:

> Files /home/xxxx/myprojects/company/apps/product/package/test/fileName.java and /productdev/product/product121/java/package/test/filename.java differ

I want to the extract the file name between 'and' & 'differ'. So I used lookarounds regular expression in a grep command :

```
diff --brief --suppress-common-lines -x '*.class' -ar ~/myprojects/company/apps/product/package/test/ $env_var/java/package/test/ | grep -oP '(?<=and) .*(?=differ)'
```

which gave me:

> /productdev/product/product121/java/package/test/filename.java

I would like to display the path starting from java to the end of the text as in: **java/package/test/filename.java** ?

Comment: does the string `java` may vary?

Comment: @Avinash: at the moment no, it does not vary.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below grep command,

```
grep -oP 'and.*\/\Kjava.*?(?= differ)'
```

That is,

```
diff --brief --suppress-common-lines -x '*.class' -ar ~/myprojects/company/apps/product/package/test/ $env_var/java/package/test/ | grep -oP 'and.*\/\Kjava.*?(?=\s*differ)'
```

Comment: its a capital letter k not small letter. it discards the previosly matched characters from printing.

Answer (score 0):

For how I see it you will be getting all the files compared in both folders and will get several lines like the ones you mentioned.

So first step would be grep-ing all the lines "differ" in them. (If that command gives any other kind of lines too)

You can ignore the above step if I am wrong and didn't understand it right.

So the next step is grep-ing both the paths. For that you can use these :

```
awk '{print $2,$4}'
```

This will print only 2nd and third fields i.e., both the paths.
awk prints fields irrespective of the spaces.

Another simple way of doing it is :

```
 cut -d" " -f 2,4
```

This will also do the same.
Here with "-d" flag we are specifying a delimiter to separate strings and with "-f" flag we are specifying the number of field places to pick from(so 2nd and 4th field).

Once you get these paths you can always store them in two variables and cut or awk whatever parts of it you want.